# Geometry nodes, align instances on a face

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

I tried different ways to place corners instances on a wall model, but I can't figure how to do it so that the alignment would be automatic.

Here I post a simplified example of the problem. There is no solution proposed on this setup. (The blue/red color is the normal direction) [image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be the solution... I didn't thought about trying the Mesh Topology nodes before, it's working well.

[image]